# how to get primary key id of a registered email

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

i have a problem on my project im currently working on and
this is my Email controller
i want to get the id of an email registered in my database

```
      if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
        $imail = $form->getValue('email');
            $users = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();
            $row = $users->fetchRow($users->select('uid')->where('email = ".$imail."'));

        /*  if ($row == 1) {
                    $token = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
                    $userpass = new Application_Model_DbTable_Password();
                    $userpass->addToken($uid , $token);
                } else { $this->view->errorMessage = "Email not registered"; }
            */
        //$this->emailAction();
        }
```

i just need to get the id to be able to shift to my next function but i cant do it also
i think this might be unrelated but i did this on pure php and it works fine

```
       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $getemail = mysql_query("SELECT `uid` FROM `users` WHERE `email` ='$email'");

    $resemail = mysql_num_rows($getemail);


        if ($resemail == 0) {

            echo "Email id is not registered";

        }

            $token = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);

            $getoken = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `password_recovery` (`uid`,`token`) VALUES ((SELECT `uid` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'),'$token') ");
```

how can i do this logic in zendframework 1 thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$row = $users->fetchRow($users->select('uid')->where('email = ".$imail."'));
```

to

```
$row = $users->fetchRow($users->select('uid')->where('email = "$imail"'));
```

I think the issue is with the dots, which you still can use as:

```
$row = $users->fetchRow($users->select('uid')->where('email = "'.$imail.'"'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution of Jehad Keriaki is correct, but unsafe. Use prepared statement syntax instead, for example:

```
$row = $users->fetchRow($users->select('uid')->where('email = ?', $imail));
```

It will protect you from SQL injection attack.

Comment: does your answer have the same effect?

Comment: Sure, result is the same. It's just safer.